# Looking for a responsive theme for 1.4.1.1

Tags: theme, rwd-theme, ce-1.4.1.1

I was tasked with finding a responsive theme for an old Magento-site, but so far I found only one for version 1.4.1.1 at themeforest.net, so I wanted to ask if anyone has been in a similar situation. The theme should be as neutral as possible, but i'd be happy with just a pointer in the right direction, maybe to a theme site i might have missed.

Comment: you really should consider the upgrade of your Magento CE to recent 1.9.x version, there is lot of improvements and fixes since 1.4.1.1 and what is most important you store can have major security holes

Answer (score 0):

Try these templates

```
https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-themes-and-templates/glamour.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/rtl-template-responsive.html
http://ecommerce-themes.com/smashing-commerce-magento-theme.html
http://visionwidget.com/free-online-store-magento-themes.html
```

and you can filter on themeforest by version

```
http://themeforest.net/attributes/compatible-software/Magento%201.4.1.1
```